# MongoDB Atlas and axios in Functions throws error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios, mongodb-atlas

Trying to use `axios` in my `MongoDB Atlas` under `Functions`. Dependency `axios` was added successfully.

However following function throws axios error:

```
exports = function() {
  const axios = require("axios");
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/PowellTravis/repos?per_page=100&page=1')
  .then(function (response) {
    onSuccess(response)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

and this is the error:

```
failed to execute source for 'node_modules/axios/index.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/adapters.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js': TypeError: Cannot access member 'Z_SYNC_FLUSH' of undefined
    at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:36:10(187)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/adapters.js:16:44(41)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:20:48(77)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:18:55(63)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js:17:45(51)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/axios/index.js:22:45(73)
```

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: What version of Node are you running? `zlib.constants` was added in Node v7. If you're running something older than that, you're going to have plenty of problems

Answer (score 0):

Please update the "axios" package with any specific version <= 1.2.0. Somehow atlas trigger functions are not supporting "axios" versions > 1.2.1.
I hope this helps!